# Auto generate dummy data with Python

Tags: python

I have two text files, id and calendar. In the IDs file I have an ID at each row as below:

```
123
124
125
.
.
.
```

In the Calendar file I have the whole year of 2019 as follows:

```
1/1/2019
1/2/2019
1/3/2019
.
.
.
```

What I am trying to do is read an ID from the IDs text file and create the whole year's record in the following format:

```
id, date, sms_sent, call_in_minutes, call_out_minutes, data_usage
```

ID should be each ID picked from the IDs file
Date should be from the calendar
sms_sent: a random number between 0-25
call_in_minutes: random number between 5-30
call_out_minutes: random number between 5-30
data_usage: random number between 5-50

I want to create 356 entries(corresponding to each calendar date) against the number and after creating the 365 entries for the first number move on to the second and so on and so forth.

Would appreciate any help as I am just starting with python.

update:

Ok, so I have come up with this very crude code, this works with a smaller list of numbers. Basically I am loading the 365 calendar days in one list and the id in another.

The solution is not very elegant since 365 is not much, but the bigger list of numbers crashes the system. Is there a way to make it more efficient so that the IDs are loaded one by one, processed and then the next ID is processed?

Following is the code I have written so far, I have also written the code for generating the random data.

```
import random

lineList = list()
numbers = list()

with open('calendar.csv') as f, open('small_list.txt') as n:
  for line in f:
    lineList.append(line.rstrip('\n'))
    for number in n:
        numbers.append(number.rstrip('\n'))



print ("List comprehension:")
for x, y in [(x,y) for x in lineList for y in numbers]:
    print (x, y)




# iterate over the list
# for clientdate in lineList:
#   print(clientdate + ', ' + str(random.randint(0,25)) + ', ' + str(random.randint(10,60)) + ', ' + str(random.randint(5,25)) + ', ' +  str(random.randint(10,50)))
```

Thanks

Comment: This Q will likely be closed but before it is I would suggest that you take a look at dataclasses in Python and find code samples where dataclasses are populated. This is the PEP https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/

Comment: Thanks Rob...much appreciate your help.

Comment: It's a pleasure! After you've dug up some sample dataclass code modify it to your needs and if you get stuck on that, come back with a specific code question, we'll all pile on then :)

Comment: @RobKielty I have written most of the code, just need advise on how the process for my IDs list can be made more efficient. Would appreciate any help possible.

Comment: _I want to create 356 entries(corresponding to each calendar date) against the number and after creating the 365 entries for the first number move on to the second and so on and so forth._ What number? The ID? It might be worth taking a look at Pandas for this, I think it should simplify things somewhat. Also, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: Thanks AMC, appreciate your advise. s I mentioned earlier,  bit new to Python so there is a learning curve. Any help with the above code would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so cracked it...the solution is not very elegant but it is memory efficient and gets the job done.

```
import random

#Sample 3 - a more pythonic way with efficient memory usage. Proper usage of with and file iterators. 
with open("calendar.csv") as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip() #preprocess line
        # print(line) #take action on line instead of storing in a list. more memory efficient at the cost of execution speed.
        with open('small_list.txt') as sm:
            for data in sm:
                data = data.strip()
                # print(line, ', ' ,data)
                print(line + ', '+ data + ', ' + str(random.randint(0,25)) + ', ' + str(random.randint(10,60)) + ', ' + str(random.randint(5,25)) + ', ' +  str(random.randint(10,50)))
                with open('output.txt', 'a+') as output:
                     output.write(line + ', '+ data + ', ' + str(random.randint(0,25)) + ', ' + str(random.randint(10,60)) + ', ' + str(random.randint(5,25)) + ', ' +  str(random.randint(10,50)) + '\n')
```